# BaseURL change problem

Tags: default-settings

I installed my Civicrm with the IP address of the server which turns out to be a "Bad Idea" (TM). Now when trying to enter various posts, such as membership details or new events I keep getting "logged out" (clicking save redirects to a login page for the IP-address).

I tried changing BASEURL in the civicrm.settings.php file, then clear all caches - but I still get this behaviour. Which is extremely  annoying.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Which CMS are you using?  (Drupal, WordPress, Joomla!)  Can you access the CMS correctly?

Comment: I'm using Joomla, and yes everything else seems to be working as supposed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Administer > System Settings > Directories` and `Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs` and make sure those show the new values.  Depending on your CMS, you may need to make changes to its configuration as well.

Comment: Hmm, in Resource URLs I get
CiviCRM Resource URL = [civicrm.root]/

While Directories only return a misrendered bare html page ...

Comment: To be more specific, this is the content of Directories 
`You may configure these upload directories using absolute paths or path variables. Path Variables
[cms.root]`

Comment: If you click the help icon on those pages it will show the values of those variables for your system.